# How can we show the torsion subgroup of a group is pure?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry

I found a definition of pure subgroup: Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H\leq G$. $H$ is a pure subgoup of $G$ if $\forall h \in H$, if $h$ is divisible by $n$ in $G$, then it is divisible by $n$ in $H$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Once you write out exactly what it is you want to prove, there isn't much left to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H$ be the torsion subgroup of $G$, and let $h \in H$, of order $m$, say. Suppose $h = n g$ for some $g \in G$. Then $0 = m h = (m n) g$, so $g \in H$.